# can we say "a tropical area?

Tags: articles

What is the difference between:

a. A tropical area
b. Tropical area

in the following sentences?

- Morphological characteristic in *a tropical area* is available.
- Morphological characteristic in *tropical area* is available.

Do the two sentences have the same meaning with respect to the area?

Does the first one signify a more specific area?

Comment: With "a" - generic place. Without "a" - proper noun with non-standard capitalisation.

Comment: @Lawrence "With "a" - generic place." Huh?

Comment: "Do those 2 sentences have the same meaning re the area?" No.

Comment: "Can we say "a tropical area?" Why do you think not?

Comment: @Kris I was referring to the indefinite article indicating a 'generic' tropical area, as opposed to the no-article version referring to a place named "tropical area".

Comment: @Lawrence I'm not sure. Just think again.

Comment: @Kris Which bit do you disagree with?

Comment: While I suppose it is possible there is a place called "Tropical Area", I don't think that is the intent of the question. So I would have to say the second example is **not** grammatical. It needs "a" (or "the", depending on the intended meaning). Or it could be "... in tropical area**s** is ..." (Actually, "characteristic" in the singular, without an article, looks odd as well. Without more context...)